# Searching only mails with id greater than n

Tags: php, email, imap

I am using a php script to retrieve emails like this:

```
$inbox  = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

Since I have many emails, I want only to process new emails so I'm trying to figure out how to search emails having id greater than id `x`.

Problem is that I cannot find a single `UID` search criteria for [imap](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-search.php).

Is there any way to achieve this without having to loop all mails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147424/imap-search-for-messages-with-uid-greater-than-x-or-generally-after-my-last-s

Comment: Thx I have already tested it before asking the question `$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'SEARCH UID 5:*',SE_UID);` and it returns `Unknown search criterion`

Comment: the search is already implied: try imap_search($inbox, 'UID 5:*', SE_UID).  You're sending the equivalent of `UID SEARCH SEARCH UID 5:*`

Comment: I tried many combinations `imap_search($inbox, 'SEARCH UID 5:*',SE_UID);` ... `imap_search($inbox, 'UID 5:*', SE_UID)` ... `imap_search($inbox, 'UID 5:*')` .... `imap_search($inbox, 'UID 5:*',FT_UID)`   and I get always the same warning --> `Unknown search criterion`

Comment: What is the server software?

Comment: I use macOS Server.

Comment: I mean, the IMAP Server software.  Can you @tag me when you respond, otherwise I have no way of telling when you do so.

Comment: Can you provide the exact and entire error message you get for `imap_search($inbox, 'UID 5:*', SE_UID)`?  It looks like the PHP library may not support this search term.

Comment: @Max This gives me `PHP Notice:  Unknown: Unknown search criterion: UID (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0`; ... for my emails Iam using macOs Server app.

Comment: @Max I forgot to mention in my question that this search criteria only worked for `map_fetch_overview` function : `$emails = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, "5:*", SE_UID);` but I need also the body of mails...

Comment: That's not a search criteria, but UID SEARCH UID 5:* is a little bit redundant, since you could just get the messages directly, like you did.  This is a problem with the library PHP uses for IMAP support not supporting that search criteria.  You could rebuild it yourself if you wished.