# Fetch new emails by imap_search()

Tags: php, imap

I need to use [imap_search()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) but with date-time not just a date but I guess the imap_search() function just work with dates.

```
<?php
imap_search($stream, 'UNSEEN SINCE 20-Sep-2015 12:35:03');
?>
```

How to get all emails after specific date-time ?

Comment: The approach of getting mail since a given date-time doesn't necessarily match the question's title of "Fetch new emails by imap_search()". Is the date-time based approach a requirement, or could you simply check for higher UIDs similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147424/imap-search-for-messages-with-uid-greater-than-x-or-generally-after-my-last-s)?

Comment: @Tristu I just need to achieve that in any method, how to search with UIDs ?